# Is it possible to limit a row in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

The problem is that when I echo user information, it also echos a column that multiple times even though it has one value. I want to echo out the maximum value of that column instead of doing it multiple times depending on other columns.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users JOIN user_images ON users.username = user_images.username WHERE users.username = '$username' GROUP BY user_images.username";
```

The `users` table have one column with one value like a profile picture. The `user_images` table have one column with multiple values like posts. I also researched that `GROUP BY` should help with this problem, but it seems to be not working. Is there a way to just echo the maximum of rows or limit the other one?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Maximum of what column?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, I meant row. On the table `users` there is only going one row for each user and for `user_images` table there is going to be multiple rows of the same user. I just want to echo the maximum number of the `users` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the `*` in the `SELECT *` bit of your query so that you are only selecting one value per column that is not in your `GROUP BY` clause.

For example:

```
SELECT user_images.username, MAX(user_images.posts)
FROM users
JOIN user_images
ON users.username = user_images.username
WHERE users.username = '$username'
GROUP BY user_images.username";
```

Will return each username and the max of the posts column corresponding to that user. You can add more columns to your `SELECT` statement as long as you're only returning one record per your `GROUP BY` 
variable.

---

To return two tables for your desired outcome:

One table which is one column of posts for the specified user:

```
SELECT posts
FROM user_images
WHERE username = '$username';
```

And a second one for that username and profile image:

```
SELECT username, profile_image
FROM user_images
WHERE username = '$username'
GROUP BY username, profile_image;
```

You don't need the joins you were doing if all of these columns are in the user_images table. If you also want columns from the `users` table you can add the join back in.

Comment: The `GROUP BY` keeps limiting the amount of user posts to one. Do I have to switch everything? @efbbrown

Comment: You're filtering your query to a single username with the line `WHERE users.username = '$username'`. Then you're grouping by username so that you get just one result back for that username. I thought this was what you wanted but now it is unclear. Maybe you should include an example of the table you want your query to return so that it is more clear.

Comment: It is, but I only want to limit the `users` table and not the `user_images` table... I'm sorry for the confusion. I am still learning more about SQL @efbbrown

Comment: Once you have a join in your query you are not filtering only one table, because the join clause will only return rows that exist in both tables. So by filtering one, you are also filtering the other. For example, if you filter the `users` table to only include username `ABC`, then when you join to the `user_images` table on username you are only going to receive rows in that table for username `ABC`.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. So is there no way to filter just one table? Or is `JOIN` is something I shouldn't be using to accomplish my task?

Comment: It still isn't clear what you're hoping to receive from your query. Do you want rows that are relevant to one user or more than one user?

Comment: Yes relevant to one user. Say if a user have a profile picture and multiple posts. You would just one to echo out that one profile picture and all of that users posts. @efbbrown

Comment: If each user has only one profile picture then your original query will already return one username, one profile picture and all their posts, but the username and profile picture will be repeated in each row. SQL can only return one table per statement, so must return the same number of records for each column.

Comment: This is exactly what's happening, so you are saying there is no way to prevent that from repeating? @efbbrown

Comment: What you want to do is two separate queries. I'll add to my answer to show you.

Comment: Thank you so much. The reason why I wanted to do this in one query is because I keep getting errors trying to pass them through `fetch API` in React Native. Now the only thing I have to do is figure that part out.